# Stock e-mail client (Nexus 4) not synchronizing to IMAP SSL account since 4.2.2 update

Tags: sync, email, 4.2-jelly-bean, nexus-4, stock-email-app

I have my school's e-mail account being checked via IMAP SSL/TLS on port 993. It is an Exchange mailbox but I did not want to to use MAPI and have my device "managed" by the school.

Anyhow, this worked fine prior to 4.2.2 update. Ever since then, e-mail is not being synchronized automatically and requires me to manually press the synchronize button.

My testing:

1. Send test e-mail to self from another account
2. Set checking frequency to 5 minutes
3. Wait 10 minutes (just to pad a bit)

Still nothing. If I go to the client and manually hit refresh though, I do get the message pulled. Also, if I restart the phone, all the new messages get pulled as well.

Things I've checked:

- **Factory reset**: Reluctantly did one yesterday but, unfortunately, did not fix the issue.
- **System Settings -> Accounts -> Email**: The synchronize button icon is green, when I click on the account, "Email" setting is checked. Says "Last synced" with a time that's over 5 minutes ago.
- **System Settings -> Data Usage -> Menu -> Auto-Sync Data**: Saw that this was the issue with many people. That, however, is checked for me.
- **Wifi vs. Mobile Data**: I've tested on both and no difference in results.

Does anyone have any suggestions on things I should check or test to figure this out.

Comment: Which email app are you using? You've tagged your question with both stock-email-app and k9-mail. If it's the stock email app, what device are you on? Some manufacturers replace the email app with their own.

Comment: The N4 stock client. I was misinformed that k9 was the stock client. My apologies.

Comment: Any other information needed? This is really bugging me.

Comment: Try logging out => Restart the device => login again.

Comment: This issue is documented here, no, resolution yet: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=56219

Comment: This isn't an answer to making IMAP work, but there's an alternative solution if you don't mind spending some money: The Touchdown HD app works as an Exchange client but does not require Device Administrator - if the school activates Remote Wipe then it just wipes the email and not your whole phone. It's quite expensive for an Android app though.

Answer (score 0):

My wife has a Nexus 4 too. I suggested to delete the account and recreate it. Then the sistems ask for authorizations of xxx stuff i cant remember and after agree it works again.

Answer (score 0):

The Android stock email client has always been horrible. I've struggled with it numerous times and my simple solution has become switching to K-9. I've gotten it to (easily) work with about a half-a-dozen corporate email systems that have not wanted to play with an Android stock email client (in a number of different device manufacturer's a number of different Android version's devices). I've heard and read a number of people having had similar experiences. It's also not a surprise to me that an update has broken the stock clients' syncing. I've experienced that too.

So. Just switch to K-9 and you'll likely be fine again. And likely for good.